# Numpy - efficiently building 2d array from 1d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am building 2d array from 1d arrays in numpy (Python 2.7). I am looking for most efficient way to do it. Up to date I came up with:

```
a=np.ones(100000)

#   SUBSCRIPTING

n_dim=3
x=0

for i in xrange(0,1000):
    x=np.zeros(shape=(100000,n_dim))
    for j in xrange(0,n_dim):
        x[:,j]=a*j

# ~1.574 s/1000 loops - joinind 3 1d arrays
# ~9.162 s/1000 loops - joinind 10 1d arrays



#   STACKING

for i in xrange(0,1000):
    x=a*0.
    for j in xrange(1,n_dim):
        x=np.vstack((x,a*j))
    x=x.T

# ~1.786 s/1000 loops - joinind 3 1d arrays
# ~16.603 s/1000 loops - joinind 10 1d arrays
```

First method (subscripting) is the fastest I came up with and performance gain over the second method (stacking) grows with number of 1d arrays I am joining. As I need to repeat this step quite a bit, I wonder if there is something faster? I am willing to go with solution that loses in clarity if it offers significant performance boost.

Maybe I can try stacking arrays in a way that limits number of stacking operations (e.g. case of joining 4 1d arrays: first stack arrays 1 and 2, then arrays 3 and 4, and resulting arrays at the end).

My question is about efficiently building 2d array from 1d arrays. Values in the arrays I am using here are dummy. In the real application most of the values in 1d arrays I am joining will likely differ.

Comment: Can you provide an example with smaller inputs?

Comment: Is it about stacking in general, or about the calculation you are showing?

Answer (score 2):

Because numpy stores (by default) arrays in [row-major order](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html) it is more efficient to set the values by rows. Therefore, I would use:

```
x=np.zeros(shape=(n_dim, 100000))
for j in range(0,n_dim):
    x[j,:]=a*j
```

Alternatively, you can define `x` to be column-major, and then, this is as fast as the previous code:

```
x=np.zeros(shape=(100000,n_dim), order='F')
for j in range(0,n_dim):
    x[:,j]=a*j
```

You could also create `x` with the numpy outer product:

```
v = np.arange(n_dim)
x = np.outer(v, a)
```

Comment: Changing x=np.zeros(shape=(100000,n_dim)) to
x=np.zeros(shape=(100000,n_dim), order='F') offered significant speed up. 1000 loops took 1.344 s for 3 dimensions and 4.672 s for 10 dimensions. Thanks.  Outer product is not an option for me as in the actual case all the entries in merged 1d arrays will differ.

Answer (score 1):

This is poor way of using `vstack`; you are calling it repeatedly, creating a new `x` for each `j`

```
x=a*0.
for j in xrange(1,n_dim):
    x=np.vstack((x,a*j))
x=x.T
```

The correct way is to build a list of the arrays, and use `vstack` only once.

```
xlist=[]
for j in xrange(1,n_dim):
    xlist.append(a*j)
x = np.array(xlist).T
```

In this context `append` works just as well as `vstack`, and may be faster.  There is also a `column_stack` function.  The key difference is that I am taking advantage of the fast list append, and the ability of `array` (and `vstack`) to take many items in its argument list.

It's even better if you can write the loop as a list comprehension

```
x = np.array([a*j for j in xrange(1,n_dim)])
```

Insertion in a preallocated array is often the fastest choice.  But you should be familiar with this build-from-a-list method.

The basic `np.array` expression

```
np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

is just this, building 2d from a list of 1d arrays (or in this case lists).

```
np.array([a*0,a*1,a*2])
```

---

`jakub` noted that `np.array` is slow. For `n_dim=10`:

```
In [257]: timeit x=np.array([(a*j) for j in range(n_dim)]).T
1 loops, best of 3: 228 ms per loop

In [258]: timeit x=np.array([(a*j).tolist() for j in range(n_dim)]).T
1 loops, best of 3: 228 ms per loop
```

Apparently `np.array` is converting the input arrays to lists, and then doing its usual construction from nested lists (or something equivalent).

```
In [259]: timeit x=np.vstack([(a*j) for j in range(n_dim)]).T
10 loops, best of 3: 24.9 ms per loop
```

`vstack` on the list of arrays is considerably faster.  Faster than the iterative `vstack` (which I expected).  And basically the same as `Ramon's` row insertion (and insertion into `order='F'`)

```
In [272]: %%timeit
x=np.zeros((n_dim,a.shape[0]))
for j in range(n_dim):
   x[j,:]=a*j
   .....: x=x.T
   .....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 23.3 ms per loop
```

While `concatenate` (used by `vstack`) is compiled, I suspect it does something similar to the iterative insertion.  It is common in the source C code to create an empty target array, and then fill it with the appropriate values.

Comment: I tried your solution. It runs roughly 29 s/1000 loops for 3 dimensions.

 For 10 dimensions it was 96.638s/1000 loops. So it might be elegant but it seems extremely inefficient.

Comment: I did some timings.  In this context (joining arrays), `np.array` does poorly.  But `vstack` on the whole list does quite well.

Comment: I also did timing in the similar setup and as you wrote it was second best to insertion proposed by Ramon. Timings just for the reference, 10 dimensions: 5.5s/1000 loops, 3 dimensions: 1.4s/1000 loops. I do not know how changing order to 'F' influences my subsequent calculations . I will check which of these two methods (Raymon's insertion and your vstack) brings biggest performance gain to entire application.